# Media query dynamic active/disable script on load and resize window

Tags: css, resize, window, media-queries

I'm working with a JS masonry grid. I want disable the script in the mobile version (width less than 800px).

I am trying with the next code:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 800){
        ...execute script
    }
});
```

All JS CODE

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  if(window.innerWidth > 900){    

    /* @license minigrid v1.6.0 - minimal cascading grid layout http://alves.im/minigrid */
    !function(t){"use strict";function e(t,e,n,o,r){var i=Array.prototype.forEach,f=t instanceof Node?t:document.querySelector(t);if(!f)return!1;var s=f.querySelectorAll(e);if(0===s.length)return!1;n="number"==typeof n&&isFinite(n)&&Math.floor(n)===n?n:6,f.style.width="";var u=f.getBoundingClientRect().width,l=s[0].getBoundingClientRect().width+n,a=Math.max(Math.floor((u-n)/l),1),c=0;u=l*a+n+"px",f.style.width=u,f.style.position="relative";for(var d=[],p=[],h=0;a>h;h++)p.push(h*l+n),d.push(n);i.call(s,function(t){var e=d.slice(0).sort(function(t,e){return t-e}).shift();e=d.indexOf(e);var r=p[e],f=d[e],s=["webkitTransform","MozTransform","msTransform","OTransform","transform"];return t.style.position="absolute",o||i.call(s,function(e){t.style[e]="translate("+r+"px,"+f+"px)"}),d[e]+=t.getBoundingClientRect().height+n,c+=1,o?o(t,r,f,c):void 0});var m=d.slice(0).sort(function(t,e){return t-e}).pop();f.style.height=m+"px","function"==typeof r&&r(s)}"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return e}):"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=e:t.minigrid=e}(this);

    (function(){
        minigrid('.grid', '.grid-item');

        window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
          minigrid('.grid', '.grid-item');
        });
      })();        
  }
});
```

I have two problems with this:
  1) Doesn't work when I load the page, only works when I resize the window.
  2) Doesn't work when I change from >800 to <800. Only works with the width in the moment of loading.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVvOgz)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is only called with window resize event, to execute it when the page load you should use

```
window.onload = function() {
    //your code 
}
```

Update:

```
var oldWidth;

window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    if(window.innerWidth > 800 || oldWidth > 800){
        try {
            minigrid('.grid', '.grid-item');
        } catch(e) {
            loadLib();
            minigrid('.grid', '.grid-item');
        }

        oldWidth = window.innerWidth;
    }
});

window.onload = function() {
    minigrid('.grid', '.grid-item');
    oldWidth = window.innerWidth;
}

function loadLib() {
    // minigrid code
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/ahmedsayed87/pen/GxvyQe)

Comment: Thank you Ahmed Sayed for your help. The problem is that if I only use window.onload then doesn't work when I resize the window. Also, it does not solve the problem of disable the script when I go through >800 to <800.

Comment: If you keep both listeners, load and resize, it should work in both cases. when you go through >800 to <800 the event doesn't execute anything because of the condition you have. check the updated code if it solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you again. I have tried the new code and I think it doesn't work, always load the JS. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEaVNp

Comment: yes, there is an extra window resizer listener in your code that I didn't notice earlier, please check https://codepen.io/ahmedsayed87/pen/GxvyQe

Comment: Ahmed Sayed, thank you very much for your effort in helping me but I'm afraid it's still not working. In your codepen link still always load the script.

Comment: No problem, can you check my codepen one more time. I hope it work this time :) codepen.io/ahmedsayed87/pen/GxvyQe

Comment: Hi Ahmed! Now it works almost perfect. Works on load and works when resize from <800 to >800 but not works when resizes from >800 to <800.

Comment: you need to destroy the component when the window size decrease to <800 but according to this issue [link](https://github.com/henriquea/minigrid/issues/58) this isn't supported yet.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed for your explanation. I'm very grateful with your help that works for my needs.